# Html 5 required field validator is not showing validation message

Tags: html

I am having a simple html form with the required validator set to one of its input field, but I do not get the validation message
Can you please help where am I going wrong??

```html
<form id="newrentalform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
    <div class="tt-container">
      <input id="customer" type="text" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Movie</label>
    <div class="tt-container">
      <input id="movie" type="text" value="" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul id="movies" class="list-group"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can't reproduce on latest Chrome. Which browser do you use? You tried adding the `action` attribute?

Comment: for me works, where is the issue? if you hit submit and customer input is empty i see the error message

Comment: Sfili_81 I cannot see the error message but the textbox appears to be red as i have applied some css to it

Comment: Sebastian Brosch I have not added any action attribute to the form .. I use Google Chrome

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Zu3cQyI — I can't reproduce the problem. You need to provide a [mcve].